# Calendar of DatePicker fills whole screen

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datepicker

I have a DatePicker in my application, that consists of `DockPanels` in a `StackPanel` in a `ScrollViewer` in a `UserControl`.

The (simplified) xaml of the `UserControl` looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="project.UI1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xml:lang="de-DE"
             mc:Ignorable="d" >
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="250"/>
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
            <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Right"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top"/>
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
            <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Border},Path=ActualWidth}"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="105"/>
            <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="105"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="24"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DockPanel}">
            <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel>
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="IK-Nummer des Absenders (z.B. D-Arzt)"/>
                <Border>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding p_1}"/>
                </Border>
            </DockPanel>
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="IK-Nummer der UNI-DAV aus UV-Träger-Verzeichnis"/>
                <Border>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding p_2}" />
                </Border>
            </DockPanel>
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Datum der Erstellung durch den Leistungserbringer"/>
                <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding p_3}"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>
```

The `TextBlocks` have a 250px fixed width and hold the description of the fields while the `TextBoxes` for the user input are supposed to grow & shrink dynamically as the user resizes the window, to fit the rest of the window width.
This is why I came up with packing every `TextBlock`/`TextBox`-combo in a `DockPanel`, and stack those in a `StackPanel`.

However, when I click on the `DatePicker`, the calendar beyond spans across the whole screen:

[image]

Even though this looks quite funky, I would prefer to get the common square calendar "popup" back.

Unfortunately, I don't know what causes the calendar to go wild like this at the moment...

Comment: You said 'simplified' xaml so I'm assuming you made some changes to it before copying?  If you didn't make any changes you don't close your final `DockPanel` tag and that might be part of your problem

Comment: Woops, thanks for the heads up! I corrected my post, that was only a simplification mistake. If the closing tag wasn't part of the actual code, the view wouldn't compile at all and I would have been unable to make the screenshot shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your TextBlock style. It is being applied to the DateTimePicker because it has no key and so applies to all TextBlocks down the visual tree.

Can you give the style a key and only apply it to certain TextBlocks?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="TextBlockStyle">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="250"/>
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Right"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
</Style>
```

....

```
<TextBlock Text="IK-Nummer der UNI-DAV aus UV-Träger-Verzeichnis"
           Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"/>
```

**UPDATE:**

OR, you could just add a new TextBlock style to the DatePicker's resource to override the style higher up in the visual tree:

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding p_3}">
    <DatePicker.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"/>
    </DatePicker.Resources>
</DatePicker>
```

Comment: Of course, because the DatePicker hosts a `TextBlock`! I removed the style of the `TextBlock` from the Resources and the `DatePicker` ist back to normal again. :-) Is there any alternative to shotgun surgery of all `TextBlocks` in my Views, like setting a key for another Style and apply that only to the `DatePickers`? That would save me a lot of work as there are only a handful of `DatePickers` against a sh*tload of `TextBlocks`...

Comment: Yes I think you could probably add a new TextBlock style to DatePicker.Resources that would override the one that is causing the problem. See updated answer

Comment: Glen, you're the man and saved me from a real headache here! Thank you very much for your quick and competently help!